# how can i use Telerik Panel-bar binding to Site_map in MVC razor layout file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc, razor-2, radpanelbar

I have MVC4 project that i want to use Telerik Q2 2013 panel bar in my _layout razor file for showing my menu. it uses a site map. in Telerik website it bind panel bar with controller .but i do not know how can i get controller for my layout page or is it true (it means is it true to use controller for _layout and how can i do this ?)i try section but i cant do any thing. 
This is my _layout code:
[enter link description here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/panelbar/sitemapbinding)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    @using StackExchange.Profiling;
    @using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
                          .DefaultGroup(group => group
                              .Add("telerik.common.min.css")
                              .Add("telerik.webblue.min.css")
                              .Add("telerik.rtl.min.css")
                              .Combined(true)
                              .Compress(true))
                         )
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div style="width: 950px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div id="Header" class="span-24 last" style="height: 100px"></div>
                <div id="HeaderTitle" class="span-20 last" style="height: 50px">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div id="Content" class="span-24 last" style="height: 400px">
                    <div id="Menu" class="span-4 last" style="width: 150px; float: right; height: 450px">
                        <div class="t-rtl">
                            @{ Html.Telerik().PanelBar()
                                             .Name("PanelBar")
                                             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px;" })
                                             .BindTo("SparepartsManagement")
                                             .Render();
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right; width: 800px; height: 400px;">
                        <div id="HeadContent" style="height: 50px;">Head Content</div>
                        <div id="MainContetnt" style="height: 400px;">
                            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                            @RenderBody()
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer" class="span-24 last" style="height: 50px; text-align: center">
                    <h6 class="alt">Copyright &copy2013 artec</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
        @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
                        .DefaultGroup(group => group
                        .Add("telerik.common.min.js")
                        .Add("telerik.panelbar.min.js")
                        .Compress(true)))
    </body>
    </html>
```